# Docker Ip Failover

Tags: docker, ip, failover

I 've some problems to configure correctly a docker container with an ip failover.

I'm not very good in sysadmin, but i've configured correctly my ip failover and i would like to bind him with my docker container.

I don't know how to do, i'm unable to find any resources who explain that .

When i go to my main ip (server Debian 195.x.x.x) from the web i can see him run (apache2 default page) and when i go to the ip failover from the web i see also the apache2 default page) from my Debian server, at this point i think it's okay.

So, when i run :

```
docker run -d --name ubuntu_01 -p 62.x.x.x:9000:80 abdev/ubuntu tail -f /dev/null
```

the 62.x.x.x which is my ip failover, after that i go to the ip failover from the web, but there's again my default page (apache2 Debian, instead Ubuntu which is my docker  container).

What i have misunderstood ? Any resources, clues or help is welcome.

Sorry for my bad english, i tried to make my best.

Comment: which port did you access to ip failover  ? http://62.x.x.x:9000 or ... ?

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply, in this case i bind 62.x.x.x:9000 (ip failover) on my docker container to port 80.

I said again i'm beginner with sysadmin and also with Docker :)
Thank again for tyour time.

Comment: so you access http://62.x.x.x:9000 still saw apache2 Debian page, right ? did you checked with command : docker ps to show all running container ?   try to stop apache2 in Debian server.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's your network:

[image: network diagram]

You may have only one Docker host for now, but the point of having a *IP failover* is to be able to switch the traffic to a different host without making users change the destination IP address.

Let's assume you have 2 docker hosts which are identical, except for the IP address of their main network interface (`eth0`).

You want to run your docker container on both hosts and you want the apache web server running inside your containers to answer for the 2 IP addresses of each host.

On *docker host A*, start your docker container with `docker run -p 9000:80 ...`.

On *docker host B*, also start your docker container with `docker run -p 9000:80 ...`.

---

Now, when on your hosting provider admin panel, you assign the IP failover `62.1.2.3` to **host A**, you will be able to:

- query host **A** web server with `http://62.1.2.3:9000/`
- query host A web server with `http://192.0.0.17:9000/`
- query host B web server with `http://192.0.0.47:9000/`

Later on, when on your hosting provider admin panel, you assign the IP failover `62.1.2.3` to **host B**, you will be able to:

- query host **B** web server with `http://62.1.2.3:9000/`
- query host A web server with `http://192.0.0.17:9000/`
- query host B web server with `http://192.0.0.47:9000/`

---

It is important that you can also query your web servers with `192.0.0.17` and `192.0.0.47` IP addresses, at least, to test web servers are up and running on both hosts, whatever the IP failover setting.

Comment: To make myself better understand, i made a litle schema.
As you can see my main server (195.145.x.x) is just a gateway for my containers.
Each container have is own ip which is an ip failover.

So when you request (62.156.x.x) docker container 01 the main server with a 'bridge' or something like that desserve the http request to the good container.

I think it's possible but for the practical case, i'm not sure what to do.
I don't know if it's the good pratices or not.
Like i said before i'm not a sysadmin :<


**My schema** => http://i64.tinypic.com/157ncep.png

Comment: _IP Failover_ is a vague term that can mean different things. I would be best if you could link the documentation for the _IP failover_ feature your hosting company is providing you.

Comment: Thank for your reply, this is the documentation about the configuration of an IPFO [here](https://documentation.online.net/fr/serveur-dedie/reseau/ip-failover/debian-ubuntu)

Comment: alright, so your IP failover is just assigning a 2nd IP address to a virtual network interface on your host. I edited my answer

Answer (score 1):

Thank you very much @thomasleveil that answer actualy respond to my question.

I would have thought it would have been more complicated but finaly i did this.

For resume, i had setup my IPFO something like this :

```
source /etc/network/interfaces.d/*

# The loopback network interface
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

# The primary network interface
auto eth0
iface eth0 inet static
    address 195.x.x.x
    netmask 255.255.255.0
    gateway 195.x.x.x

auto eth0:0
    iface eth0:0 inet static
    address 62.x.x.x
    netmask 255.255.255.255
```

Run my container with :

```
$ docker run -it --name ubuntu_01 -p 9000:80 docker/box tail -f /dev/null
```

I can access to my container from the web from main server IP and IPFO.

I think this is a basic configuration but it's work !

I would like up vote your answer but stackoverflow forbidden the up vote from new member.

Thank you again for your time :)